# Infinite subset of R contains a non-empty open interval

Tags: real-analysis

I'm preparing for the exam, trying to solve this.

Every infinite subset of R contains a non-empty open interval.

Every infinite subset of R contains a non-empty closed interval.

Every infinite subset of R has a non-empty closed subset.

Which one of these are true? If false can you give counterexamples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- For the first two, consider the set of integers.$\\[4pt]$

  For the third one, note that a singleton set is closed.

Comment: So, the first two are false, because for every interval we have real numbers which are not integers in it, and the third one is true because every nonempty set has a one-point subset, which is closed. Am I correct?

Comment: You mean every interval has real numbers which are not integers.

Comment: yep, edited that part

Comment: Then yes, that reasoning yields correct answers.